# useAuthContext fails when communicating with backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, express, prisma

I am building a full stack real estate app using reactJs, postgres, express & prisma.

When I want to check if there is a token stored in my localstorage, it fails and returns an error message giving a 404 not found.

I tried to search for explanation but it's always the same story and it doesn't work in my situation.

Eventually I want to be able to get the data from the logged in user and use it on my front end. If anyone has any additional tips on how to do this, please let me know!

**== API ==**

*Index.js*

```
const authRoutes = require('./routes/auth');
const userRoutes = require('./routes/user');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require("cors");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");

dotenv.config();

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Testing')
})

app.use('/auth', authRoutes);
app.use('/user', userRoutes);


app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log("app is running!")
});
```

*user.js (routes)*

```
const { PrismaClient } = require('@prisma/client')

const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const prisma = new PrismaClient();

router.get('/user/me', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
      where: { id: req.user.id },
    });
    console.log(user);
    res.status(200).json({ user });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json(error);
  }
});


module.exports = router;
```

**== APP ==**

*Authcontext.js*

```
import { createContext, useReducer } from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "../config/axios";

const AuthContext = createContext()

const authReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'LOGIN': 
            return { user: action.payload }
        case 'LOGOUT':
            return { user: null }
        default:
            return state
    }
}

const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(authReducer, {
        user: null
    })

    useEffect(() => {
        const user = localStorage.getItem('token')

        if (user) {
            dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN', payload: user })
        }
    }, [])

    const getUserInfo = async () => {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
        if (token) {
            try {
              const res = await axios.get(`/user/me`, {
                headers: {
                  'x-auth-token': token,
                },
              });
              console.log(res.data.user);
              dispatch({
                type: 'LOGIN',
                payload: {
                  user: res.data.user,
                },
              });
            } catch (err) {
              console.error(err);
            }
          } else {
            delete axios.defaults.headers.common['x-auth-token'];
          }
      };
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const verifyUser = async () => {
            if (!state.user) {
                await getUserInfo();
            }
        };
        verifyUser();
    }, []);
    
    const register = async (registerData) => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.post("/register", registerData);
            return response.data;
        } catch (error) {
            if (!error.response) {
                return { status: "ERRROR", message: "No Server Response" };
            } else if (error.response.status === 409) {
                return error.response.data;
            } else if (error.response.status === 400) {
                return error.response.data;
            } else {
                return error.response.data;
            }
        }
    };
    
    const login = async (loginData) => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.post("/login", loginData);
            localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.token);
            await getUserInfo();
            return response.data;
        } catch (error) {
            if (!error.response) {
                return { type: "ERROR", message: "No Server Response" };
            } else if (error.response.status === 400) {
                return error.response.data;
            } else if (error.response.status === 401) {
                return error.response.data;
            } else {
                return error.response.data;
            }
        }
    };
    
    const logout = async () => {
        try {
            localStorage.removeItem("token");
            dispatch({
                type: "LOGOUT",
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.response);
        }
    };

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ ...state, dispatch, register, login, logout }}>
            { children }
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}


export {AuthContext, authReducer, AuthContextProvider}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please do not redeclare root route name in `authRoutes` and `userRoutes`. With current shape, you'd have to call it:

```js
await axios.get(`/user/user/me`, cb)
```

Instead, to keep axios calls as they are declared now, declare routes as below:

```js
router.get('/me', cb)
```

then, you'll be able to call it properly

```js
await axios.get(`/user/me`, cb)
```

You can read more in [express.js documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#router).

Comment: I have to do this in my AuthContext right?

Comment: Nevermind, figuered it out! Thanks for this problem